# GSG Signal add-on alternative for Blender!

Tags: animation

jut wondering if you guys know, if there is any add-on, like the Signal add-on from greycalegorilla (GSG), to make looping animation easier in blender.

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: Never heard of it. Long answer: Could you possibly be a little more specific? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially "Be specific" and "Make it relevant to others".  Please try at least to explain what this Signal add-on does or provide a link to a good explanation. Nobody's got time to search the internet for answers about every obscure tool that exists.

Comment: thanks for you replay, I thought that signal was more known, but ok. Is hard to explain, "Signal allows you to instantly create complex animations with intricate loops, realistic noise, additive effects, and all with no keyframes.", here is the link I think is a better way to put it, https://greyscalegorilla.com/downloads/signal/